# Easiest way to multiply vector values together?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, linear-algebra, vectormath

I've got a silly question. I took a vector math class about 10 years ago and could've sworn I remembered an operation that allowed me to multiply the values of a vector together like so:

```
Vector3 v1 = new Vector3(1, 0, 2)
Vector3 v2 = new Vector3(5, 5, 5)
//Vector3 v3 = SomeVectorOperation(v1, v2) = (1 * 5, 0 * 5, 2 * 5)
```

Now in reviewing all my notes, and everything I can find online, it doesn't look like this is a common operation at all. Of course I can write a function that does it:

```
Vector3 VectorMult(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2) {
    return new Vector3(v1.x * v2.x, v1.y * v2.y, v1.z * v2.z);
}
```

So far I've found at least a few instances where an operation like this would be helpful, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't exist already in some form. So, I guess I have two questions:

1. Is there an easier way to get the result I'm looking for than making my own custom function?
2. Is there a reason why there is no standard vector operation like this to begin with?

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When we electrical engineers want to sound smart, we call it the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)), but otherwise it’s just the “element-wise product”.

What library are you using? GLSL? Eigen? GSL? We can look for how to do element-wise multiplication in it. (It can often be accelerated using SIMD, so an optimized implementation provided by a library will be faster than your hand-rolled function.)

Edit: Unity calls this [`Vector3.Scale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Scale.html): “Multiplies two vectors component-wise.”

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad to know it has a name. I'm using Unity, which has built-in vector functions of all sorts, but so far I haven't noticed one that does this specific operation

Comment: Looks like they call it [`Vector3.Scale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Scale.html): “Multiplies two vectors component-wise.”

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I missed that. In retrospect, that's all a scale operation really is, I suppose. Thank you so much.

Comment: I can't believe they thought having a static method called `Scale` of all things was better than using a `*` operator... Can't wait for Extension operators

Comment: I agree with avoiding `*` for this.  Someone who's got dot-product on their mind could easily read `v1 * v2` and think it's a dot-product.